# LstListing caption number setting

Tags: sectioning, captions, listings

I am using `\package{lstlisting}` to display some matlab code in the latex.
My codes are placed in the appendix with labels. Given below is excerpt of my code:

```
% block of codes
 \clearpage
 \appendix
 \chapter{Appendices}
 \section*{Appendix A.1}\label{appendix_A.1}
   \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Simulation 1},label={simulation_1},language=Matlab]
        % some matlabcode
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Simulation 2},label={simulation_2},language=Matlab]
        % some matlabcode
    \end{lstlisting}
 \section*{Appendix A.2}\label{appendix_A.2}
```

And here is my output:

Chapter A: Appendices
Section: Appendix A.1

"block of matlab code" with caption Listing A.1: Simulation 1

"block of matlab code" with caption Listing A.2: Simulation 2

Section: Appendix A.2

The thing that I dislike about this is that when I refer sections
and listings it seem to share same name. It would be nice if I could 
have something like Listing 1: Simulation 1, Listing 2: Simulation 2.
Anyone for the help? Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to remove `\thechapter` from `\thelstlisting`.  Note that `\section*` by itself cannot be referenced by `\label`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{listings}

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Yada Yada}

 \clearpage
 \appendix
  \renewcommand{\thelstlisting}{\arabic{lstlisting}}
 \chapter{Appendices}
 \section*{\refstepcounter{section}Appendix \thesection}\label{appendix_A.1}
   \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Simulation 1},label={simulation_1},language=Matlab]
        % some matlabcode
    \end{lstlisting}

    \begin{lstlisting}[caption={Simulation 2},label={simulation_2},language=Matlab]
        % some matlabcode
    \end{lstlisting}
  %
 \section*{\refstepcounter{section}Appendix \thesection}\label{appendix_A.2}

\end{document}
```